# Validation error: "The tag: "meta" doesn't have an attribute: "robots" in currently active versions"

Tags: html, meta-tags

In Dreamweaver, when validating a HTML file against the following;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

I get the following error message;

> Error  {Filename}  The tag: "meta" doesn't have an attribute: "robots" in currently active versions.   Line: 10

Can anybody help with why this is failing the validation check on this line:

```
<meta name="ROBOTS" content="INDEX, FOLLOW" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, turns out I missed the quotation mark at the end of the last meta tag;

```
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="description here...end./>
<meta name="DESCRIPTION" content="description here...end."/>
```